# как менять цвет текста Логотипа исходя из фона

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как менять цвет текста Логотипа исходя из фона. шапка прилипает к верху с прозрачным фоном, логотип чёрный нужно чтобы при скролле когда например через фото будет проходит менял цвет и был видным исходя из фона под ним, на чём можно реализовать это? Примерно как в https://setters.agency/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариантов масса. Как и готовых примеров. Вот один из них:

```js
// Detect request animation frame
var scroll = window.requestAnimationFrame
  || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
  || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
  || window.msRequestAnimationFrame
  || window.oRequestAnimationFrame
  // IE Fallback, you can even fallback to onscroll
  || function(callback){ window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60) };
var lastPosition = -1;

// my Variables
var lastSection = false;
var replaceItemTop = -1;
var replaceItemBottom = -1;
var replaceItemHeight = -1;
 
// The Scroll Function
function loop(){
  var top = window.pageYOffset;
  // my variables

  // my sections to calculate stuff
  var sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
  var replaceContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.js-replace');
  var replaceItem = document.querySelectorAll('.js-replace__item');

  if (replaceItem.length > 0) {
    // get top position of item from container, because image might not have loaded
    replaceItemTop = parseInt(replaceContainer[0].getBoundingClientRect().top);
    replaceItemHeight = replaceItem[0].offsetHeight;
    replaceItemBottom = replaceItemTop + replaceItemHeight;
  }

  var sectionTop = -1;
  var sectionBottom = -1;
  var currentSection = -1;
  
  // Fire when needed
  if (lastPosition == window.pageYOffset) {
    scroll(loop);
    return false;
  } else {
    lastPosition = window.pageYOffset;

  // Your Function
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(sections, function(el, i){
    sectionTop = parseInt(el.getBoundingClientRect().top);
    sectionBottom = parseInt(el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom);

    // active section
    if ( (sectionTop <= replaceItemBottom) && (sectionBottom > replaceItemTop)) {
      // check if current section has bg
      currentSection = el.classList.contains('section--bg');

      // switch class depending on background image
      if ( currentSection ) { 
        replaceContainer[0].classList.remove('js-replace--reverse');
      } else {
        replaceContainer[0].classList.add('js-replace--reverse')
      }
    }
    // end active section

    // if active Section hits replace area
    if ( (replaceItemTop < sectionTop) && ( sectionTop <= replaceItemBottom) ) {
      // animate only, if section background changed
      if (currentSection != lastSection)  {
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--replace-offset', 100 / replaceItemHeight * parseInt(sectionTop - replaceItemTop) + '%');
      }
    }
    // end active section in replace area

    // if section above replace area
    if ( replaceItemTop >= sectionTop ) {
      // set offset to 0 if you scroll too fast
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--replace-offset', 0 + '%');
      // set last section to current section
      lastSection = currentSection;
    }

  }); 

}

// Recall the loop
scroll( loop )
}

// Call the loop for the first time
loop();

window.onresize = function(event) {
  loop();
};
```

```css
/* variables */
:root {
  --black: #000;
  --white: #fff;
  --color-1: #000;
  --gutter: 2rem;
  /* this value is going to be changed by javascript */
  --replace-offset: 50%;
  --replace-offset-2: calc((100% - var(--replace-offset) ) * -1)
}

/* set image position */
img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

/* Sticky Footer */
.body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.footer {
  padding: calc(var(--gutter) * .5);
  background-color: var(--black);
  color: var(--white);
}

/* without fixed header this makes no sense */
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: calc(var(--gutter) * .5);
  text-align: center;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid;
  padding: calc(var(--gutter) * .25);
  border-radius: calc(var(--gutter) * .25);
  font-size: 2em;
}

.logo--invert {
  background-color: var(--black);
  color: var(--white);
  border-color: var(--white);
}

.section {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding-top: var(--gutter);
  padding-bottom: var(--gutter);
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.section--bg {
  background-color: var(--color-1);
}

/**
  This is the interesting part
**/

/* align content above each other without absolute */
.js-replace {
  display: grid;
}

.js-replace__item {
  grid-row: -1 / 1;
  grid-column: -1 / 1; 
  overflow: hidden;
  will-change: transform;
}

/* item to replace with */
.js-replace__item {
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--replace-offset) * 1));  
}
.js-replace__content {
  /* fixes problem with calculating correct height in js */
  border: 1px solid transparent; 
  will-change: transform;

  transform: translateY(calc(var(--replace-offset) * -1));
}

/* previous replace item*/
.js-replace__item--active {
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--replace-offset-2) * 1));  
}
.js-replace__item--active .js-replace__content {
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--replace-offset-2) * -1));  
}


/* REVERSE ANIMATION */
.js-replace--reverse 
.js-replace__item {
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--replace-offset-2) * 1));  
}
.js-replace--reverse 
.js-replace__content {
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--replace-offset-2) * -1));
}

/* previous replace item*/
.js-replace--reverse 
.js-replace__item--active {
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--replace-offset) * 1));  
}
.js-replace--reverse 
.js-replace__item--active .js-replace__content {
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--replace-offset) * -1));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="body">
  <header class="header"> 
    <!-- replace content -->
    <div class="header__logo  js-replace">
      <!-- item to replace -->
      <div class="js-replace__item  js-replace__item--active">
        <div class="js-replace__content">
          <div class="logo">Logo</div>
        </div>
      </div>  
      <!-- end item to replace -->
     
      <!-- item to replace with -->
      <div class="js-replace__item">
        <div class="js-replace__content">
          <div class="logo  logo--invert">Logo</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end item to replace with -->
    </div>
    <!-- end replace content -->
  </header>

  <main class="main">
    <section class="section--1  section">
      <h1 class="section__title">

      </h1>
    </section>
    
    <section class="section--2  section  section--bg">
      <h1 class="section__title">

      </h1>      
    </section>
    
    <section class="section--3  section">
      <h1 class="section__title">

      </h1>
    </section>
    
    <section class="section--4  section  section--bg">
      <h1 class="section__title">

      </h1>      
    </section>
    
    <section class="section--5  section">
      <h1 class="section__title">

      </h1>
    </section> 
  </main>

  <footer class="footer">
    &copy; Phuc Le - Webdeveloper
  </footer>
</body>
```

Вот [источник](https://codepen.io/whatthephuc/pen/QQagBj).

Так же, можно воспользоваться [Midnight.JS](http://aerolab.github.io/midnight.js/)

Принцип достаточно прост. Вы расставляете темным блокам отдельный класс, за который потом цепляется скрипт и делает подмену одного логотипа другим.